# Create database from Doctrine model with Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I've created a new database with the SQL `CREATE DATABASE` command to host my application tables. I would now generate the database from my Symony 2.1 project using Doctrine. I already have the correct mapping YML-PHP entities but when I try to use the command

```
php app/vendors doctrine:schema:create
```

it fails on a query that I run inside my application. What I don't understand is why it seems that it's trying to boot my bundle and so obviously it fails because the queries that I execute don't find the tables. How can I generate the new database?

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydatabase.mytable_menu' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That command only creates the database for you. You will need to run this command to generate the actual database tables for your entities.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: I tried but I still get the error about the table not found. More specifically, I have a container service which runs that query in the constructor to initialize a variable with the array of records. It seems that trying to initialize the container the query is executed and obviously fails

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just comment out the query while you generate the tables to avoid the error?

Comment: It's always good practice to run `--dump-sql` before the `--force` flag in order to tell what's being done to the databse.